# Execute chmod in Dockerfile on Raspberry pi /dev/spi*

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, dockerfile, hypriot

I have a problem with my Dockerfile. I installed `py-spidev` on my Docker container to fetch data from a sensor.
Everything works and is installed in the container.

My only problem is that the folder `/dev/spi*` has only read-write rights for root. I need reading rights on www-data. If I execute a `chmod 666 /dev/spi*` on a running container, everthing works fine. I want that the `chmod` to be executed in the Dockerfile.

https://github.com/legionth/westfall-pi/blob/master/Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

In your Dockerfile, just add this line:

```
RUN chmod 666 /dev/spi*
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me:
`Step 28 : RUN chmod 666 /dev/spi*`
---> Running in e85d1fc63d8d
chmod: cannot access ‘/dev/spi*’: No such file or directory
As I said, I can edit the rights afterwards in the running container. but not in the Dockerfile

Comment: the error message means the directory doesnt exists in your docker image, therefore try to install py-spidev directly from your Dockerfile